# Ag-grid row models: pagination vs virtual paging vs viewport

Tags: performance, ag-grid

As title says, I would like to know how to decide which row model to choose and the reason why, depending on how the data change and the number of rows, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewport - Use when you need to show realtime data, the server will maintain an open connection to update the grid whenever new data is ready.

Pagination/Virtual Paging - these are both about the same, just depends on what you want for your UI. In both situations you would use them if you have a lot of rows to show, but don't want the user to wait 10 min for the server to respond. Probably works best if you sort/filter on the server side.

Other notes:

In my opinion, if you have pagination, then don't have any scroll. I hate scrolling a table to realize that what I am looking for isn't on that page, then scrolling through another page. The only exception for this is if you have some sorting to your paging, like if the first page was all the A's, or had only from 2000, or just January's data.

Also, Pagination can be used in situations where you don't have a lot of data to request from the server, it could just be a UI preference.

Comment: In my case, I can have a table with up to 50k rows (by a raw estimation), which data keeps updating... but it could be also sorted and filtered. By now, I'm using viewport rowmodel adapting the row count every time I filter. Is that the best practice in my case?

Comment: sounds right to me, so long as you are filtering and sorting on the server side as it says in their [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/#gsc.tab=0)